# ServerScriptService.Size:4: attempt to index nil with 'Humanoid'

Tags: roblox

Cant figure out what the problem is

```
while wait(.5) do 
    local children = game.Players:GetChildren("Humanoid")
    for i = 1, #children do
        local hum = children[i] .Character.Humanoid
        hum.HeadScale.Value = children[i].leaderstats.Points.Value/50 +1
        hum.BodyHeightScale.Value = children[i].leaderstats.Points.Value/50 +1
        hum.BodyWidthScale.Value = children[i].leaderstats.Points.Value/50 +1
        hum.BodyDepthScale.Value = children[i].leaderstats.Points.Value/50 +1
        hum.WalkSpeed = children[i].leaderstats.Points.Value/3.12
        hum.JumpPower = children[i].leaderstats.Points.Value
        hum.MaxHealth = children[i].leaderstats.Points.Value+25
    end
end
```

was trying to get a simple size script to work.

Answer (score 0):

The `attempt to index nil with Humanoid` error is telling you that the object that you are trying to grab the Humanoid out of doesn't exist. This line specifically :

`local hum = children[i].Character.Humanoid`

When a player joins the game, there is an indeterminate amount of time before their character model actually spawns into the world. So between when they join and when their character spawns, the [Player.Character](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player#Character) property is nil.

Your code does not handle the possibility that the character model is nil, and you are trying to access the humanoid immediately.

A safer approach is not to use a loop, but to observe changes to the leaderstats values and react to those changes. So in your code that creates your leaderstats objects, do something like this :

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local function updateCharacter(hum : Humanoid, points : number)
    local bodyScale = (points / 50) + 1
    local walkSpeed = points / 3.12
    local jump = points
    local health = points + 25

    hum.HeadScale.Value = bodyScale
    hum.BodyHeightScale.Value = bodyScale
    hum.BodyWidthScale.Value = bodyScale
    hum.BodyDepthScale.Value = bodyScale
    hum.WalkSpeed = walkSpeed
    hum.JumpPower = jump
    hum.MaxHealth = health
end


Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    -- when a player joins the game, give them a leaderstats folder
    local leaderstatsFolder = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstatsFolder.Name = "leaderstats"
    local pointsValue = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    pointsValue.Name = "Points"
    pointsValue.Value = 0 -- or load from dataStores
    leaderstatsFolder.Parent = player

    -- listen for changes to the points and resize the character
    pointsValue.Changed:Connect(function(newValue)
        -- escape if the character doesn't exist
        local character = player.Character 
        if character then
            updateCharacter(character.Humanoid, newValue)
        end
    end)

    -- when the character model spawns into the world, update it immediately with the player's point size
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        updateCharacter(character.Humanoid, pointsValue.Value)
    end)
end)
```